# Segue is reverted automatically

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboardsegue

I have a Storyboard Menu controller that go a second controller with segue,

I create a custom class that inherit `ViewController`, it is empty and I assign it to the second controller

When I push the segue with `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ReservasSegue" sender:self];` It do the segue but when it finish automatically revert the Segue withouth any message or say something.

If I quit the custom class to the second controller It works perfect

**SecondController.h(ReservasListado.h)**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ReservasListado : ViewController


@end
```

SecondController.m(ReservasListado.m)

```
#import "ReservasListado.h"


@interface ReservasListado ()

@end

@implementation ReservasListado

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that `@interface ReservasListado : ViewController`

Should be `@interface ReservasListado : UIViewController`

I dont know why... but it works